# Why isn't my SVG path rotating on scroll on iPhones?

Tags: javascript, paths, bug, svg, iphone

I'm trying to get a path inside an inline SVG in the Header of my website to rotate when the user scrolls the page. It's a really neat feature, but it's not working on some iPhones.

Here's the relevant code:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    scrollRotate();
};

function scrollRotate() {
    var logocog = document.getElementById("ebo4dmab8whh14_tr");
    //console.log(logocog);
    if (logocog) {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            logocog.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset/4+"deg)";
        });
    }
}
```

Note: "ebo4dmab8whh14_tr" is the path I'm rotating here.

This code works perfectly on a desktop both on the development site (dev.shinyverse.com) and on the production site (shinyverse.com) in every browser I've tested it on.

However, on an iPhone, it only works on the development site and does not work at all on the production site. The browser and/or version of the iPhone doesn't seem to matter. Android phones (and other brands of phones) don't seem to experience this problem.

I've tried to diagnose the issue in BrowserStack with no improvement. I've tried disabling the security and caching plugins just in case. I've tried error trapping out the 'style' null error possibility in the code just in case with no improvement. I've even tried straight-up cloning the development site over to the production environment, with no change or improvement whatsoever.

Is there something I'm missing or not understanding here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but ios will have a few problems with the onscroll event. You can try refer to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad#answer-2863570